# How to get a return from a method called from a foreach

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Enum holding the Resource Ids, called Resources.Id.

Another script `Resources.cs` has methods to generate specific strings according to the Enum provided. I want to iterate through all the Enums storing some strings related to them inside a Dictionary.

The code runs well until the last return call in QtyAddress. I did some Debug and the stack trace gets lost right after the return.

PlayerData.cs

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Resources
foreach (Resources.Id resource in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Resources.Id))) 
{
    string key = Resources.QtyAddress(resource);
    list.Add(key , "0");
}
```

Resources.cs

```cs
public static string NamePlural(Id id) 
{
    string String;

    switch (id) 
    {
        case (Resources.Id.Technology):
          String = "Technology";
          break;

        default:
          String = "NONE";
          break;    
    }

    return String;
}

public static string QtyAddress(Id id) 
{
    string String;
    switch (id) 
    {
        case (Resources.Id.Technology):
          String = string.Format("{0}Qty", NamePlural(id));
          break;

        default:
          String = "NONE";
          break;
    }
    return String;
}
```

No error message is coming on the console or in the stack trace.

The debug goes through return call in `NamePlural()` and stops right before the `QtyAddress()` return. All Strings are set correctly according to the debugger.

Comment: using the word "String" as a variable name is a confusing thing to do.  Id suggest a name change.

Comment: in addition to @BugFinder comment, also call a Dictionary list is a bit confusing. About the sample which values are defined in Resources.Id enum, in your code all values that are different from Technology return "NONE" if there are more than one values different from Technology you will receive a [System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.] error the second time you call list.Add with "NONE" key.

Comment: I agree with you guys about the names. I changed them to make easy identify them here. In the original code they have long names.

Comment: About the double-entry of the "NONE" key, it's really a mistake that I did. But the code doesn't run until it reaches the "NONE" key. It stops while computing the first key "TechnologyQty";

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please edit the question and include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!!!

There was a small typo in one of the addresses. But somehow the compiler wasn't throwing the error then kept on an infinite waiting, leaving us without notice.

Basically it was trying to add a duplicate index key since it is not possible the builder should show the error, but it's not showing.

Thank you, guys!!!